# sending form data to server by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I am new with ajax and want to make a to-do-list.

for add-form submit method() ,I have an if-else .the else works and give me alert in its situation but if doesnt work I think it's about my post method.

by the way it's my jquery code :

```
$('#add_task').submit(function(event) {
/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault();
var title = $('#task_title').val();
if(title){
 //ajax post the form
 $.post("/add", {title: title}).done(function(data) {
   $('#add_task').hide("slow");
   $("#task_list").append(data);
 });
}
 else{
   alert("Please give a title to task");
}
});
```

and when I click on my add btn the console output shows me a 404 not found error and refer to this line of my jquery main file that I download from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js: it is :

```
f.send(a.hasContent&&a.data||null),b=function(c,e){var h,i,j;if(b&&    (e||4===f.readyState))if(delete Xc[g],b=void     0,f.onreadystatechange=m.noop,e)4!==f.readyState&&f.abort();
```

it's my controller :

```
  public function postAdd() {
  if(Request::ajax()){
    $todo = new Todo();
    $todo->title = Input::get("title");
    $todo->save();
    $last_todo = $todo->id;
    $todos = Todo::whereId($last_todo)->get();
    return View::make("ajaxData")
    ->with("todos", $todos);
 }
}
```

and my route:

```
Route::controller('/', 'TodoController');
```

thanks for time

Comment: If it shows a 404 error, the `/add` url is not found

Comment: @adeneo:thanks for reply. I used the tutorial  http://www.packtpub.com/article/building-a-to-do-list-with-ajax.. so I think everything related to jquery version and the jquery code that I wrote above . what's your idea about url? what should it be?

Comment: Huh, it should be a valid URL to something that responds, there's no magic, if you have an URL, the server has to respond when that URL is called.

Comment: @adeneo: I add my code . please check again my question . thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "submit button" to simple button and change as below.

```
$('#add_task').click(function() {
    var titleField = $('#task_title');
    if(titleField.length > 0){
        $.post("/add", {title: titleField.val()}).done(function(data) {
            $('#add_task').hide();
            $("#task_list").append(data);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please give a title to task");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an problem with routing in Laravel. This routing should work:

```
Route::post('add/',array('uses' => 'TodoController@add'));
```

Answer (score 0):

404 HTTP Status errors in AJAX are only related to the URL you are sending your data. Change `/add` with something your backend can handle, like a simple PHP file, because `/add` means you need some htaccess/nginx rewrites to be done.

Anyway, it's a simple tutorial, and I'll downvote you for copying code claiming to be yours from: [packtpub](http://www.packtpub.com/article/building-a-to-do-list-with-ajax)

You should do a simple ajax request like this:

```
    $.ajax({ url : 'ajax.php', data: {title:title}, type: 'POST', success:
       function(response) {
          // exec success code
       }
    });
```

Never do internet tutorials if you have no idea about programming because you'll never get them to work. It's just a simple php file that you need to code, and change it's url from that tutorial in your Route:: controller, though, that tutorial is way too complex for a to-do list.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it just by changing:

```
$.post("/add", {title: title})
```

to:

```
 $.post("http://localhost/Blueprints/to-doListWithAjax/public/index.php/add", {title: title})
```

it didnt found localhost://add so I gave it complete addrerss
 .

THANKS ALL FOR REPLIES